# How do you create a inner 3D perspective effect in Photoshop CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, perspective

I have a client who really wants something like this but unable to find a better quality anywhere. Is there a way to recreate this effect in photoshop or illustrator?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the 3d>Extrude in Photoshop? Have you tried the Blend tool in Illustrator? Care to share your efforts in researching the answer?

Comment: I tried using the Layer Style > Blend. Messed around to see if I could get similar effect but no result. To be honest I don't know where to start looking. Most of the tutorial I found is nothing related to this idea.

Answer (score 4):

The technique that I use probably isn't the most efficient, but it works and should give you the image you provided. I'm going to assume you have a basic knowledge of Photoshop tools like selection, layers, etc. This technique relies on the "Actions" window and function of Photoshop CS4.

1. Start with a basic outline of the object you want to 3D-ify.

   [image]
   <sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>
2. Open up the Actions Window (found under Window in the taskbar).

   [image]
3. We're going to "record" an action. Once we record an action, we can "replay" it over and over again. This will make a bunch of layers to give the "3D" effect. BE CAREFUL. Everything you do after you press "record" becomes part of the Action. We need to do four very simple things.

   - Duplicate the Shape layer.
   - Select the new Shape layer.
   - Move the Center of the image to the bottom.
   - Resize the new Shape layer by ~1%.
4. Click the "Create new action" button at the bottom of the Actions window.

   [image]
5. Using the keyboard, press CMD+J (Ctrl+J on PC) to duplicate the layer.
6. Using the keyboard, press Option+[ (Alt+[ on PC) to select the new Shape layer.
7. Using the mouse, click and drag the "centroid" (little circle dot) from the center of the shape to the bottom of the image.
8. Scale the new shape layer to 99.6% (or something similar). This will make the duplicate shape look proportionately smaller. Apply the transformation (checkmark in top right or CMD+Return).

   [image]
9. Open the Actions window and hit "Stop". Just like filming a video, your new action will stop recording. If you did things correctly, your Action should look like this.

   [image]
10. Now, all you have to do is "play" the action on the shape layer a few dozen times to "extrude" the shape. It's not perfect and generates a ton of layers but it works. Feel free to consolidate some of the layers if you want. You'll eventually get something like this.

    [image]
11. The reason it doesn't look great yet is because it doesn't have any shadows. 3D objects have shadows. This is where this technique falls short because it takes a bit of a creative eye to see where shadows "should" be. I just selected pieces of the depth shape and created a solid color layer. Set it to black and opacity ~30% (whatever you want, really).

    [image]
12. By using the selections from the previous steps, you can make new layers that affect only certain "shadowy" areas. Apply black to transparent gradients (G on the keyboard) to make the near-to-far gradients. Again, this takes a little bit of an artistic eye and there's no exact science to it. Play around with gradients to darken areas you think should be darker.

    [image]
13. That's about it! Play around with it. Flatten the layers and do normal PS stuff to it. It's not perfect or polished, but that's one method. Once you get the hang of the process, you can make something as polished as what you initially posted. You can even see the "ribs" in what you posted - partial evidence that they used a similar Action/Duplication/Resizing approach.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! I hope you continue contributing. Please let us know if you have any questions about how the site works

Comment: You can record a fill action with very low opacity to gradually make the color darker when you extrude inwards. You can also merge the layers immediately if you want but that is beside the point. + 1 very well done